# Haskell function definition and caching arrays

Tags: haskell, memoization

I have a question about implementing caching (memoization) using arrays in Haskell.  The following pattern works:

```
f = (fA !)
  where fA = listArray...
```

But this does not (the speed of the program suggests that the array is getting recreated each call or something):

```
f n = (fA ! n)
  where fA = listArray...
```

Defining fA outside of a where clause (in "global scope") also works with either pattern.

I was hoping that someone could point me towards a technical explanation of what the difference between the above two patterns is.

Note that I am using the latest GHC, and I'm not sure if this is just a compiler peculiarity or part of the language itself.

EDIT: ! is used for array access, so fA ! 5 means fA[5] in C++ syntax.  My understanding of Haskell is that (fA !) n would be the same as (fA ! n)...also it would have been more conventional for me to have written "f n = fA ! n" (without the parentheses).  Anyway, I get the same behaviour no matter how I parenthesize.

Comment: A similar question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951012/when-is-memoization-automatic-in-ghc-haskell - though a little more clearly stated, and with some good responses.

Answer (score 8):

The difference in behavior is not specified by the Haskell standard.  All it has to say is that the functions are the same (will result in the same output given the same input).

However in this case there is a simple way to predict time and memory performance that most compilers adhere to.  Again I stress that this is not essential, only that most compilers do it.

First rewrite your two examples as pure lambda expressions, expanding the section:

```
f = let fA = listArray ... in \n -> fA ! n
f' = \n -> let fA = listArray ... in fA ! n
```

Compilers use let binding to indicate sharing.  The guarantee is that in a given environment (set of local variables, lambda body, something like that), the right side of a let binding with no parameters will be evaluated at most once.  The environment of fA in the former is the whole program since it is not under any lambda, but the environment of the latter is smaller since it is under a lambda.

What this means is that in the latter, fA *may* be evaluated once for each different n, whereas in the former this is forbidden.

We can see this pattern in effect even with multi argument functions:

```
g x y = (a ! y) where a = [ x ^ y' | y' <- [0..] ]
g' x = (\y -> a ! y) where a = [ x ^ y' | y' <- [0..] ]
```

Then in:

```
let k = g 2 in k 100 + k 100
```

We might compute 2^100 more than once, but in:

```
let k = g' 2 in k 100 + k 100
```

We will only compute it once.

If you are doing work with memoization, I recommend data-memocombinators on Hackage, which is a library of memo tables of different shapes, so you don't have to roll your own.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to find what is going on is to tell the compiler to output its intermediate representation with `-v4`. The output is voluminous and a bit hard to read, but should allow you to find out exactly what the difference in the generated code is, and how the compiler arrived there.

You will probably notice that `fA` is being moved outside the function (to the "global scope") on your first example. On your second example, it probably is not (meaning it will be recreated on each call).

One possible reason for it not being moved outside the function would be because the compiler is thinking it depends on the value of `n`. On your working example, there is no `n` for `fA` to depend on.

But the reason I think the compiler is avoiding moving `fA` outside on your second example is because it is trying to avoid a space leak. Consider what would happen if `fA`, instead of your array, were an infinite list (on which you used the `!!` operator). Imagine you called it once with a large number (for instance `f 10000`), and later only called it with small numbers (`f 2`, `f 3`, `f 12`...). The 10000 elements from the earlier call are still on memory, wasting space. So, to avoid this, the compiler creates `fA` again every time you call your function.

The space leak avoidance probably does not happen on your first example because in that case `f` is in fact only called once, returning a closure (we are now at the frontier of the pure functional and the imperative worlds, so things get a bit more subtle). This closure replaces the original function, which will never be called again, so `fA` is only called once (and thus the optimizer feels free to move it outside the function). On your second example, `f` does not get replaced by a closure (since its value depends on the argument), and thus will get called again.

If you want to try to understand more of this (which will help reading the `-v4` output), you could take a look at the [Spineless Tagless G-Machine](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/Papers/spineless-tagless-gmachine.ps.gz) paper ([citeseer link](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/peytonjones92implementing.html)).

As to your final question, I think it is a compiler peculiarity (but I could be wrong). However, it would not surprise me if all compilers did the same thing, even if it were not part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, thank you for your answers which helped a lot, and I will definitely check out data-memocombinators on Hackage.  Coming from a C++-heavy background, I've been struggling with understanding exactly what Haskell will do (mainly in terms of complexity) with a given program, which tutorials don't seem to get in to.