# Memoizing a Haskell Array

Tags: haskell, memoization

Continuing with my looking into CRCs via Haskell, I've written the following code to generate a table for CRC32 calculation:

```
crc32Table = listArray (0, 255) $ map (tbl 0xEDB88320) [0..255]

tbl polynomial byte = (iterate f byte) !! 8
    where f r = xor (shift r (-1)) ((r .&. 1) * polynomial)
```

This correctly generates the table. I want to make frequent accesses to this table but 1) don't want to hardcode the results into code and 2) don't want to recalculate this table every time I reference it.

How would I memoize this array in Haskell? The Haskell memoization pages haven't given me any clues.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is: crc32Table is already the memoized tbl function.

Comment: Really? How do I tell if it is already memoized?

Comment: memoizing is the process of indexing a *function*'s arguments by a data structure.  Array is already a data structure, so memoizing doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @Muchin, you could use `Debug.Trace` and `crc32Table = trace "Evaluating" $ listArray (0, 255) ...`. That will print "Evaluating" whenever the expression is evaluated.  If it is memoized, it should only print "Evaluating" once.

Comment: @Muchin - unless crc32Table is a function or something like Num a => Array a, you can be pretty sure that it is only computed once.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I called crc32Table over and over, it would re-create the array over and over. But now, I don't understand when Haskell will cache the array and when it recreates it.

Comment: But you don't call crc32Table, you just index into it.  Anything at the top level will persist as long as you can reference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discussion at this question should help explain what's going on: [When is memoization automatic in GHC Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951012/when-is-memoization-automatic-in-ghc-haskell)

As folks have said in comments, crc32Table, *if it is monomorphically typed* should only be computed once and retained.