# GHC optimization

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

The two Haskell functions below seems to differ only by whether the index variable is implicit or explicit but the difference in performance is by two orders of magnitude.

This function takes about 0.03 seconds to calculate mfib 30:

```
let mfib = (map fib [0..] !!)
  where
    fib 0 = 0
    fib 1 = 1
    fib x = mfib (x-1) + mfib (x-2)
```

This function takes about 3 seconds for mfib 30:

```
let mfib i = map fib [0..] !! i
  where
    fib 0 = 0
    fib 1 = 1
    fib x = mfib (x-1) + mfib (x-2)
```

I'm guessing it has to do with GHC inline rules and have been trying to add inline/noinline pragmas to get matching performance.

EDIT: I understand how doing a lookup into the lazy list can be used to memoize the fib function and why the traditional definition of fib is very slow. I was expecting the memoization to work in the second function as well as the first and don't understand why it is not.

Comment: The key is *memoization*. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easier to understand these differences when looking at the desugared code, so here are partially desugared versions of the two functions.

```
let mfib = let fib 0 = 0
               fib 1 = 1
               fib x = mfib (x-1) + mfib (x-2)
           in (!!) (map fib [0..])
```

versus

```
let mfib = \i ->
               let fib 0 = 0
                   fib 1 = 1
                   fib x = mfib (x-1) + mfib (x-2)
               in map fib [0..] !! i
```

Note that in the second program, the expression `map fib [0..]` appears inside `\i -> ...`, so it will (normally, without optimizations) evaluated for each value of `i`. See [When is memoization automatic in GHC Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951012/when-is-memoization-automatic-in-ghc-haskell)

Comment: I did some tests on the repl to try to confirm this and seems correct. I also looked at the link provided by @alexey-radkov about memoization and the suggestion there was that it had to do with the first function being monomorphic and therefore shared between calls, whereas the second is polymorphic, but I couldn't confirm this e.g. by redefining `map` to be monomorphic.

Comment: TL;DR Because `map fib [0..]` is in a lambda it isn't shared, but garbage collected between (recursive) calls. Correct?

Comment: @Mikkel Right, and the reason is because (though it doesn't in this case) it could depend on `i`, and then couldn't be shared. (And this is usually a good way to see what will be shared without doing the desugaring first.)

Answer (score 7):

No, this has nothing to do with inlining. The difference is that `mfib = (map fib [0..] !!)` has no arguments. It's still a function of course, but evaluating that function does upfront not require to pass any argument. In particular, evaluating this `mfib` will generate the `fib` list in a way that it can be reused for all indices.

OTOH, `mfib i = map fib [0..] !! i` means the entire `where` block will only get considered when you actually pass an argument `i`.

The two are only different if you evaluate a function many multiple times again and again. Unfortunately for the second version, the functions own recursion already calls it again and again! So `mfib (x-1) + mfib (x-2)` then needs to do the entire work of `mfib (x-1)`, *and then again* the entire work of `mfib (x-2)`. So `mfib n` takes more than twice the computational cost of `mfib (n-1)`, therefore `mfib` ∈ *O* (2<sup>*n*</sup>).

That's incredibly wasteful, because most of the terms in `mfib (x-2)` are also already in `mfib (x-1)` and could simply be re-used. Well, that's exactly what your first version does, because it computes the `fib` list once and for all indices, so evaluating `mfib (x-1)` will already do most of the work that can then simply be re-read by `mfib (x-2)`, reducing the complexity to polynomial.

Comment: A little additional explanation for _why_ the `where` block is re-evaluated: it's because `i` is in the `where` block's closure. If you were to write it as `let mfib = \i -> map fib [0..] !! i where ...` it'd be just as fast as the eta-contracted version. That said, I'm surprised GHC didn't spot an opportunity to apply the full-laziness transformation and float `fib` outside the binder.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I did indeed try putting the `i` in a lambda, but it makes no difference -- memoization still not "working".