# Will let construction optimize something in list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, optimization, compiler-optimization

I should write a function that sums elements in a list comprehension block.

Let's take these two functions just for example:

```
letSum :: [Int] -> [Int]
letSum xs = [result | x <- xs, y <- xs, let result = x + y, result > 10]

normalSum  :: [Int] -> [Int]
normalSum xs = [x + y | x <- xs, y <- xs, x + y > 10]
```

**Question:**

- Is the second function summing x and y twice in opposite to the first one?
- If not, how does it work?

Comment: Yes, the second one computes the sum twice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second function will compute the sum twice – there is no explicit sharing to be performed here, nor the Haskell performs memoization (source: [When is memoization automatic in GHC Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951012/when-is-memoization-automatic-in-ghc-haskell))

`let` lets the sum be computed once and used in several places, so the first function will be *slightly* faster.

---

EDIT:

Someone in the comments mentioned CSE (common subexpression elimination) as possible optimization that may occur here. I have tried compiling your function with `-ddump-cse` to discover whether it will happen, but although I didn't find any mentions of `normalSum`, the output was too mysterious to me. However, my answer should be true if you build your function without `-O*` flag. I will update my answer if I find more information about it.

Comment: I’m not sure it’s computed twice.  Doing CSE would compute it just once, or even just using cheap strictness (which ghc does).

Comment: I could not find any information when exactly is CSE performed

Comment: Ghc does very little CSE, but it does use cheap strictness.  Comparing the core for the two functions is the way to find out.