# What is the role of Haskell's evaluation strategy in Memoization via Representable

Tags: haskell, memoization, representable

The article [Memoization via Representables](https://iagoleal.com/posts/representable-memoize/) does a great job at explaining how to memoize recursive functions via Representables. It starts by implementing the Fibonacci sequence as a fixed point of `fibOp`:

```
fibOp :: Num a => (Natural -> a) -> (Natural -> a)
fibOp v 0 = 0
fibOp v 1 = 1
fibOp v n = v (n-1) + v (n-2)

fix f = let x = f x in x

fibNaive :: Num a => Natural -> a
fibNaive = fix fibOp
```

This implementation is not efficient as it calculates the same values many times.

The article goes on to introduce the mutual inverse functions `streamTabulate` and `streamIndex` (which will later be generalised in the `Representable` type class). These functions allow us to implement a memoized versions of `fibNaive`:

```
fibSmart :: Num a => Natural -> a
fibSmart = fix (streamIndex . streamTabulate . fibOp)
```

And it is at this point where the article gets somewhat "handwavy":

> If we compose our tabulation function with fibOp, we get a function turns a function v into a Stream, over which we can index to get back a function. In this case, however, the same stream is shared for all arguments.

What does this mean *exactly*? Apparently this memoization technique works because of Haskell's lazy evaluation strategy and because it tries not to evaluate expressions "unnecessarily". For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951092/402428) mentions that Haskell computes any given expression at most once per time that its surrounding lambda-expression is entered. The surrounding lambda-expression of `streamTabulate` however is entered once per iteration induced by the surrounding `fix`, which would mean `streamTabulate` is potentially evaluated multiple times.

Why and how does this approach work? Which aspect of Haskell's evaluation strategy does it exploit?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "The surrounding lambda-expression of `streamTabulate`". I don't see what you mean by that.

Comment: `fibSmart` can be expanded to `\n -> fix (\f -> streamIndex $ streamTabulate $ fibOp $ f) n`. So if my understanding of that other SO answer I linked is correct, the surrounding lambda expression of `streamTabulate` is `\f -> ...` .

Comment: FWIW, I made all code for exploring this topic available via GitHub: https://github.com/mduerig/representable-memo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function:

```
fibSmart :: Num a => Natural -> a
fibSmart = fix (streamIndex . streamTabulate . fibOp)
```

can indeed be expanded by inlining `(.)` to:

```
fibSmart = fix (\f -> streamIndex (streamTabulate (fibOp f)))
```

but the lambda `\f -> ...` here is only entered once by the `fix` function.

You can also see that by further inlining `fix`:

```
fibSmart = let f = streamIndex (streamTabulate (fibOp f)) in f
```

Comment: The inlining of fix is what does the trick indeed. Fascinating!

Comment: @michid, note that inlining `fix` is not required for the memoization. Adding a `{-# NOINLINE fix #-}` pragma doesn't change the performance much.

Comment: For a further exercise I implemented the same thing in Java. It was interesting to see where I had to manually add lazy evaluation and memoization to make this work. Most obviously the stream needs a lazy tail. But only after manually inlining `fix` did I see the performance gain. Interestingly after inlining the memoization of `streamTabulate` becomes very explicit. 
https://gist.github.com/mduerig/2116556dc525f4a0a12cf6fae415fb93

Comment: @michid I'm honestly not sure how your Java `fix` works exactly, but it *looks* like it doesn't "do anything" until the function it returns is actually called (all the code is inside the `R apply(T t)` method of the `new Function`). Whereas Haskell `fix` "does its thing" once and for all *before* the returned function receives any argument (`fix` might not even be returning a function, so it *can't* work that way). By inlining it, are you effectively doing the same thing: "pre-computing" the fixpoint before you invoke it, instead of on every invocation?

Comment: @Ben, "Whereas Haskell fix "does its thing" once and for all before the returned function receives any argument". AFAICS this is the reason why this memoization technique works in Haskell but not in Java.